# docker nginx load balancing not working with Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, nginx, docker, sails.js

Ok been trying this setup for a full day now. I cannot get Nginx to connect the domain name that `azure` gave me to my `node` `docker` containers.

I'm using `Azure` to create a `VM`.
The `DNS name` is `scout-1j013s34.cloudapp.net`
The `virtual IP address` is `191.237.66.86`

I can `ssh` into the `VM` with `ssh monty@scout-1j013s34.cloudapp.net -p 61777`. I'm not sure why I need to specify a port?

The `VM` is running `Ubuntu 14.04`. 
I installed `docker` myself.

I found and followed the following tutorial [`A sample Docker workflow with Nginx, Node.js and Redis`](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/)

I built, and ran the containers as shown below.

[image: docker processes]

Here is my `nginx.conf` file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    upstream node-app {
          least_conn;
          server node1:1337 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
          server node2:1337 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
          server node3:1337 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
          listen 80;

              server_name 191.237.66.86 scout-1j013s34.cloudapp.net www.scout-1j013s34.cloudapp.net;

          location / {
            proxy_pass http://node-app;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          }
    }
}
```

when I enter `http://scout-1j013s34.cloudapp.net/` into the browser address bar, it times out.

***Update:***
I have `EXPOSE 1337` in my `Dockerfile` to expose the 1337 ports for each node container.

For each node container I ran `docker run -it --name node1 --link mongo:MONGODB -v /home/monty/scout/backend-api/:/scout-sails mlennie/scout-sails bash` changing the name to node2 and node3 for the next 2 then I went into each container and started the `sails.js` app with `sails lift`.

Then I started the nginx container and linked it to the 3 node containers with the command `docker run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 --link node1:node1 --link node2:node2 --link node3:node3 mlennie/nginx`

Comment: What is in your Nginx log? And have you [linked](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) to nodes to your Nginx container? And have you exposed port 1337 on the nodes?

Comment: @OrangeTux I just updated the question to answer your questions. I just added logging paths to the nginx.conf file. So I will try to find the logs. I believe that I did link the nodes to the nginx and I did expose the 1337 ports on the nodes in the dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it working I needed to manually add an endpoint through Azure management portal with a port of 80.

Comment: By the default only management ports are open (SSH), you need to manually open the endpoints you need.